# Using a div value within a SQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

this is my updated link:

`<a href="Portfolio.php?val="'.$row['profile_name'].'" id="link">`

and this is my updated SQL query

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM profile 
 WHERE profile_type = value=".$_REQUEST['val']."";
```

at the moment this is bringing back nothing does this code look correct or do i need to alter it in anyway ??

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you append the id on the `href` like `Portfolio.php?id=1` and then you can use `$_GET['id']` to read it back when that page is loaded. And make sure to properly sanitize it before using on the SQL query.

Comment: because at the moment there are about 20 of these links on one page and they are being being brought from a database the `href=""` that is within the link wont actually be used @Prix

Comment: You can set links dynamic as well ...

Comment: `value` is not valid as attribute for the `<a>` tag.

Comment: @RolandJansen then how would you do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Pass that value in query string

```
<a href="Portfolio.php?val=".<?php echo $row['field']; ?>." " id="link"> </a>
```

Use it in query like:

```
 "SELECT * 
 FROM profile 
 WHERE profile_type = ".$_REQUEST['val']." ";
```

Comment: would this work if i used 
`<a href="portfolio.php?val='.$row["value"].'"` @Anandsolanki

Comment: Yes just change your syntax like <a href="portfolio.php?val='.<?php echo $row["value"]; ?>.'"

Comment: would this not be `<a href="portfolio.php?val='.<?php echo $row["value"]; ?>.'">;` because you only have one closing bracket and two opening

Comment: @Arnandsolanki I have altered my code but it will not bring back any results any ideas i will alter my code above to what i have got

Comment: Try this query my friend, it will surely works: "SELECT * 
 FROM profile 
 WHERE profile_type = ".$_REQUEST['val']." ";

Comment: no sorry i echoed the sql query and it doesnt seem to be getting the value any ideas ?

Comment: Finally get solution. Good :)

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out - `value` is not a attribute for an anchor tag.

You need to update the anchor tag `href` attribute to be something like

```
<a href="Portfolio.php?value=1" id="link">Click Here</a>
```

This will send the value to the php side when clicked.  Which can then be retrieved by the php side using the `$_GET` array.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['value']))
{  // Check that the value was passed
   $val = $_GET['value'];

   // TODO: Use val in SQL as required.
}
?>
```

Comment: how would i alter this with the example above ??

Comment: @user3387522 You need a good grasp of what you are trying to achieve in order to understand the question and answers being posted here.  Please read up some tutorials/guides on how to update sql data, try starting at - http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers.

Comment: @user3387522 Your code sample is lacking details, and clearly, anything I post here will not work as it lacks those details.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the value = part. the query should be

"SELECT * 
 FROM profile 
 WHERE profile_type = ".$_REQUEST['val']." ";